# Performing efficient external system queries during kafka stream processing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, akka-stream, apache-kafka-connect, alpakka

I would like to consume an event from a Kafka topic, inject it into a database, perform some queries, remove the event from the database and produce the results of the query back to a topic.

This looks like what was asked in [External system queries during Kafka Stream processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064430/external-system-queries-during-kafka-stream-processing)

As an exemple, I could perform geolocalisation queries against a spatial DB, where I would first insert coordinate from the received message, perform a lookup to compute some neighborhood, remove the coordinate from the db and forward downstream a result message containing the neighborhood.

I could use a tranformer to perform the queries and forward the enriched messages dowstream as suggested in the first solution in the previous link. However, I have some performance concerns with KafkaStream when doing this as it results in a per event query on the Db.

- Could I use some stream pattern like windowed stream to batch several coordinates together and perform only one query per batch ?
- How KafkaStreams would react in case of DB failure ?
- Would the KafkaStream thread being stuck ?
- Is there some timeout where the stream application would fail ?
- Once the DB back, would the KafkaStream thread recover nicely ?
- What would be the corner cases of such a design ?
- Would it be better to develop an external service to perform the db
  query with KafkaConnect or alpakka and read the requests from a topic
  and write responses to another topic ?

Comment: How is "best approach" to be determined???  Minimal resource usage, code line count, least likely to fail, etc.???

Comment: Can you elaborate on what role the database is playing here? Writing to and reading from the database as part of a stream process sounds like a pattern that's not always appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I updated my question to be more precise with an usage exemple.