# External processing using Kafka Streams

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

There are several questions regarding message enrichment using external data, and the recommendation is almost always the same: [ingest external data using Kafka Connect and then join the records using state stores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42064430/external-system-queries-during-kafka-stream-processing/42076117?noredirect=1#comment104833862_42076117). Although it fits in most cases, there are several other use cases in which it does not, such as IP to location and user agent detection, to name a few.

Enriching a message with an IP-based location usually requires a [lookup by a range of IPs](https://redislabs.com/redis-best-practices/indexing-patterns/ip-range-indexing/), but currently, there is no built-in state store that provides such capability. For user agent analysis, if you rely on a third-party service, you have no choices other than performing external calls.

We spend some time thinking about it, and we came up with an idea of implementing a custom state store on top of a database that supports range queries, like Postgres. We could also abstract an external HTTP or GRPC service behind a state store, but we're not sure if it is the right way.

In that sense, what is the recommended approach when you cannot avoid querying an external service during the stream processing, but you still must guarantee fault tolerance? What happens when an error occurs while the state store is retrieving data (a request fails, for instance)? Do Kafka Streams retry processing the message?

Comment: "abstract an external HTTP or GRPC service behind a state store" - Isn't that what Interactive Queries does?

Comment: IQ allows you to get data from a store into your application -- the question is about getting external data into a `Processor`.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, `KeyValueStore#range(fromKey, toKey)` is supported by build-in stores. Thus, it would be good to understand how the range queries you try to do are done? Also note, that internally, everything is stored as `byte[]` arrasy and RocksDB (default storage engine) sorts data accordingly -- hence, you can actually implement quite sophisticated range queries if you start to reason about the byte layout, and pass in corresponding "prefix keys" into `#range()`.

If you really need to call an external service, you have "two" options to not lose data: if an external calls fails, throw an exception and let the Kafka Streams die. This is obviously not a real option, however, if you swallow error from the external lookup you would "skip" the input message and it would be unprocessed. Kafka Streams cannot know that processing "failed" (it does not know what your code does) and will not "retry", but consider the message as completed (similar if you would filter it out).

Hence, to make it work, you would need to put all data you use to trigger the lookup into a state store if the external call fails, and retry later (ie, do a lookup into the store to find unprocessed data and retry). This retry can either be a "side task" when you process the next input message, of you schedule a punctuation, to implement the retry. Note, that this mechanism changes the *order* in which records are processed, what might or might not be ok for your use case.

Comment: Isn't letting the application die a good option for stateless applications when external service outages are rather unusual (SLA 99.9%)? Handling reboot on the infrastructure side allows applying backoff policies, service status check, etc.

Comment: I guess that is up your application requirements -- from a Kafka Streams point of view, there is no real issue IMHO.